# Set Default option from Angular Filter

Tags: angularjs

I have a select list which is being generated with a filter:

```
<select ng-model="item.SAC">
    <option ng-repeat="code in SACCodes | filter:{group: item.SACGroup}" value="{{code.code}}">{{code.code}} - {{code.description}} - {{code.group}}</option>
</select>
```

When `item.SACGroup` changes I want to automatically select the first valid option (so that the select box never turns blank).

```
$scope.SACCodes = [
{'code':'034', 'description':'FTG Support Steel', 'group':'footings'},
{'code':'037', 'description':'Masonry Wall FTGs', 'group':'footings'},
{'code':'032', 'description':'S.O.G. Rebar', 'group':'slabs'},
{'code':'033', 'description':'S.O.G. (DBL.Mat)', 'group':'slabs'}
];
```

Comment: use [**`ngOptions`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Comment: @Jordash Any updates ? Did you solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [WORKING JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/jutoqerovu/edit?html,js,output) example for the same:

**Explanation**:

As pointed out in the comments by @AnikIslamAbhi, you should use `ng-options` here:

```
<select ng-model="item.SAC" ng-options="code.code as codeLabel(code.code, code.description, code.group) for code in SACCodes | filter:{group: item.SACGroup}">
</select>
```

Define the `codeLabel` method on your scope:

```
$scope.codeLabel = function(code, description, group) {
  return code + " - " + description + " - " + group;
};
```

For your original problem of setting a **default option** value, add `ng-init` to your `<select>` element:

```
<select ng-model="item.SAC" ng-options="code.code as codeLabel(code.code, code.description, code.group) for code in SACCodes | filter:{group: item.SACGroup}" ng-init="item.SAC = SACCodes[0].code">
</select>
```

Hope it helps you.