# Make a filter by words without hiding them

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a code that allows me to filter a JSON object by both the name and the title. I have an array with a few words, I would like to make this same filter but without hiding the words, just mark them based on my array.

```
$scope.arrayFilter=["bad,bill,mikle,awesome,mosa"];
```

Is it possible to perform this filter by default when I start my application ?. Thank you very much.

https://jsfiddle.net/ryvu49jt/

```
$scope.data = [{
 title: "Bad",
 name: 'bill'
}, {
 title: "Good",
 name: 'Goe'
}, {
 title: "Great",
 name: 'Brad'
}, {
 title: "Cool",
 name: 'yan'
}, {
 title: "Excellent",
 name: 'mikle'
}, {
 title: "Awesome",
 name: 'mosa'
}, {
 title: "Horrible",
 name: 'morteza'
} ]

}).filter('highlight', function($sce) {
 return function(text, phrase) {
   if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('(' + phrase + ')', 'gi'),
     '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

   return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
 }
})
```

Currently if I type a word in a text field, it is filtered by both the name and the title of my JSON object. Are marked but disappear. I just want them to be marked, not disappear.

thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `ng-options` and `ng-init`. Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646716/set-default-option-from-angular-filter

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you also filtering the `<li>` just delete the filter
and also concatenate the the `item.name`
like this example.

```
<div class="container" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data ">
           <span ng-bind-html="item.title +' '+ item.name | highlight:search"></span>
        </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

it would search only on the `bind-html`

Here is a working plnkr where search over the  elements
[EXAMPLE](https://embed.plnkr.co/BwmDhGekSrx9bvN8I4nU/)

Comment: great! But as I said in the question, I need to make the filter not by the text field, but with the values present in the array.$scope.arrayFilter=["bad,bill,mikle,awesome,mosa"];
  I am sure that if you help me, I will understand much more angular.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the filter from your `ng-repeat` and leave the other code same as it is

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in data">
```